# Phalcon multi module with shared layout

Tags: php, phalcon

I am new to Phalcon php framework and I got this problem. I want for every module to have simple view. For example:

user's view will say: 'hello this are my users'

articles's view will have: 'this are all the articles'

so in this case I need common layout (or whatever) where are all my head, css tags, also my footer, my nav bar and so on.

for this purpose I followed [this repo](https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple-shared-layouts).

So... in my `/modules/Home/module.php` I have:

```
$di['view'] = function() {
    $view = new View();
    $view->setViewsDir(__DIR__ . '/views/');
    $view->setLayoutsDir('../../common/layouts/');
    $view->setTemplateAfter('main');
    return $view;
};
```

in `/modules/common/layouts/main.phtml` I have all my html, heads etc..

in `/modules/Home/views/index.phtml` I have "hi there"

in `/modules/Home/views/edit.phtml` I have "edit my home screen"

now when i go to "/" ( root dir ) it calls `home/index`, and I see ONLY "hi there" and nothing else.

Is it possible this to be done ?

Answer (score 1):

You may check their github mvc samples, https://github.com/phalcon/mvc/tree/master/multiple-shared-views

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are pointing to/modules/**H**ome/views/index.phtml but your url is home/index it is all case sensitive, so I suggest 2 things: rename Home to home in your file structure and if that still does not work go to your HomeController look for the indexAction and just echo something to see if the code gets executed. Then report back your results

Comment: hmm, i didn't think of case sensitive problem.. I used a tool to generate my app and now works. But this defiantly could  have caused the problem. Thanks mate!